# What HMM (Hidden Markov Model) compression libraries available for .NET?

Tags: .net, compression, hidden-markov-models, markov-models

I am looking for a library that use Markov Models/Hidden Markov Models for data compression. I will need to use it from the .NET. I googled for MM/HMM compressors but didn't find any helpful reference (I can be be  a bad googler though).

Any relevant link would be most cordially appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Accord.NET](http://accord-net.origo.ethz.ch/) together with [the article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69647/Hidden-Markov-Models-in-Csharp.aspx).